# How do I colorize the Google Tango (Nash) pointcloud with an RGB texture?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, google-project-tango

I'm trying to write a shader using the [Unity Pointcloud Example from Github](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity) as base in order to render the pointcloud with different colors than the default blue/pink. It's my first time working with 3D data and shaders so my understanding about how things work is likely off. I noticed the density of the pointcloud I have is vastly different from the 1280x720 image I am using so maybe every time the shader does a texel lookup, it's hitting a black color? My [pointcloud shows up as tiny black dots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MASvU.jpg) instead of the expected mix of colors from the RGB image that I have attached to the material that has the shader on it. Here's my shader code:

```
    Shader "Tango/TextureTest" {
    Properties {
      _MainTex ("RGBA Texture Image", 2D) = "white" {} 
   }
   SubShader {
      Tags {"Queue" = "Geometry"}

      Pass {    

         CGPROGRAM

         #pragma vertex vert  
         #pragma fragment frag 

         uniform sampler2D _MainTex;    

         struct vertexInput {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
            float4 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
         };
         struct vertexOutput {
            float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
            float4 tex : TEXCOORD0;
         };

         vertexOutput vert(vertexInput input) 
         {
            vertexOutput output;

            output.tex = input.texcoord;
            output.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, input.vertex);
            return output;
         }

         float4 frag(vertexOutput input) : COLOR
         {
            float4 textureColor = tex2D(_MainTex, input.tex);  
            return textureColor;
         }

         ENDCG
      }
   }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

In the Unity Editor, I've created a new material and added a random RGB image to it. To use this new material + shader, I replaced the Pointcloud material + shader used in the Pointcloud Unity Example with mine. So I have two questions: is my shader incomplete/incorrect and what am I missing in understanding the concept of using a texture in the shader, especially related to this Tango pointcloud scenario?

Thanks.

My Tango device is running Nash.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - you won't have any success that way unless you accumulate 3d hits in a fixed view and hope for them to finally achieve full coverage - very unlikely, given the nature of the beast

You have two solutions -
The first is to generate a mesh using Delauney triangulation or any other technique that will stitch the points you do have into a surface.  You can then let the graphics engine figure out all of the points in between - your texture coordinates are generated for the points you do know, texel coordinate you don't know are interpolated -  [here's a movie of that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4s3anRf-uLk) --

Now, I have to be the first to admit, after chasing that snipe for two months, its the wrong direction for all the wrong reasons - tl;dr is that Tango data returns are a statistical process, i.e. you have to proceed with the assumption that while statistically accurate to some degree over time, individual points returned by Tango are neither accurate nor reproducable - hence volume visualization techniques are the way to go, as in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2dr4RUSHfbY) - in that one, there are various booboos in texture application however it is actually working with a multiaxis fused model, as opposed to the former that only operates when view is directly aligned with camera locus and attitude at time of collection.

As for the actual creation of shaders, that is a different response - but I would argue there's not much point in selecting the shader until you know how you're weaving that cloud of points into a surface (first movie) or into a 3D model (second movie) -  I cannot stress how much the first is a "very bad idea"